# game of cards in java array and arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So basically I'm making a game of cards and I'm trying to remove a `certainAmount` of cards off from the top of my deck and then return that `certainAmount` as an array of size `certainAmount` and I can't figure out why my logic is incorrect

```
private ArrayList<Card> cards;

public Deck() {
    cards = new ArrayList <Card>();

    for (int type= 0; type<=4; type++){ 
        for (int value=1; value<=9; value++){ 
            Card newCard = new Card (value, type); 
            cards.add(newCard); 
        }
    }

}

public Deck(Deck other) {
    cards = new ArrayList<Card> (other.cards); 
}


public Card getCardAt(int position) {
    Card gottenCard = cards.get(position); 
    return gottenCard; 
}


public int getNumCards() {
    int sizeOfArrayList = cards.size(); 
    return sizeOfArrayList;  
}

//remove certain amount (numCards) of cards from top of arraylist 
public Card[] deal(int numCards) {  
    Card[] newArray = new Card[numCards];

    //assigning removed card to new array positions 
    for (int newArrayPosition=0; j<newArrayPosition;newArrayPosition++) { 
        newArray[j] = cards.remove((cards.size()-1)); 
    for (int newArrayPosition=0; j<newArrayPosition;newArrayPosition++) { 
        newArray[j] = cards.remove((cards.size()-1)); 
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: how you know your logic incorrect?

Comment: the error I'm getting within our submit server says : java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<0> but was:<4>

@cainiaofei

Comment: I think you'd better post the more detailed code

Comment: @emmynaki the current code has nothing to do with `assertion` as well.

Comment: what does it have to do with? @nullpointer

Comment: `java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<0> but was:<4>` you would get this error when you are using `Assertion`. It's not a compilation failure but a test failure then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I have understood from your question, I believe I have an answer that can help you. I think the use of ArrayList's are imperative in this situation. ArrayList's allow for easy removal and addition of values without needing to worry about 'nullPointerExceptions.' Therefore, my answer uses ArrayList's that contains integers that represent cards. In your scenario, just replace 'Card' with 'Integer' in the ArrayList's Generic Parameter. My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Answers {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Answers main = new Answers();
         // Original Deck
         ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();

         // Add to original deck
         cards.add(1);
         cards.add(2);
         cards.add(3);
         cards.add(4);
         cards.add(5);

         System.out.println("Removed Cards Deck: " + main.deal(3, cards));
             // Removed Cards Deck: [1, 2, 3]

          System.out.println("Original Deck: " + cards); 
             // Original Deck: [-1, -1, -1, 4, 5]
     }

     public ArrayList<Integer> deal(int numCards, ArrayList<Integer> deckOfCards) { 
          // Deck that will contain the removed cards
          ArrayList<Integer> newCardsArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

          for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) { 
               newCardsArray.add(deckOfCards.get(i)); 
                    // Add to remove cards deck

               deckOfCards.set(i, -1); 
                    // Set taken cards in original deck to '-1'
          }
          return newCardsArray;
     }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know it'd be a lot easier this way! The instructions of our project however are made so that we don't use array list for the deal method--I'm not sure what the purpose is though haha